# How to alter a function so it can count any alphabet character?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a function that counts DNA bases within a sequence and returns a count of them separately. The function is

```
def baseCounts(DNA):
    for base in DNA:    
        numofAs = DNA.count('A')
        numofCs = DNA.count('C')
        numofGs = DNA.count('G')
        numofTs = DNA.count('T')

    return numofAs, numofCs, numofGs, numofTs
```

Now, I need to alter the function so it is not restricted to just the DNA alphabet of A, C, G and T.
I know I need to add the alphabet argument to the function

```
BaseCounts(DNA, alphabet):
```

However, I don't know what or how to code the rest of the for loop for any character? Keep in mind they have to be added separately?

Comment: Can you put an example of what exactly would be your input and expected output?

Comment: BTW your current code is very inefficient, the loop is totally unnecessary and makes the same 4 counts N times (where N is the length of DNA)

Answer (score 3):

You can use counter:

```
from collections import Counter

DNA = 'ATCGBBHHTTCCGGHH'
c = Counter(DNA)
print(c)
```

#### Output:

```
Counter({'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'H': 4, 'A': 1, 'G': 3, 'T': 3})
```

will return a Counter object which is a specialized dictionary where the keys correspond to the values encountered in the sequence `DNA`, and constitute your `alphabet`, and the values are the count of these values in `DNA`